# How to build a native binary that includes a javaAgent?

Tags: micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I would like to build a native binary from a micronaut application. However, this application uses a javaAgent at runtime (to instrument code and send traces to Datadog). I haven't found a way to build the native binary including the runtime javaAgent. Is that even possible?

Comment: I believe the basic problem is that a JVM agent runs outside of the JVM and monitors it, but a native image is not JVM based at all, so there's no way to hook a regular java agent up to it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build a native binary that includes an agent (in my case the Datadog Java agent).

I did that by passing a flag to the native-image command, like this:

```
native-image … -J-javaagent:/opt/java/lib/dd-java-agent.jar …
```

[Here](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/overview/Options/) is the documentation for this flag on the native-image tool.

> -J: pass an option directly to the JVM running the native-image builder